# How do I animate each individual HTML tag to load in a sequence via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am polishing a jQuery script to make a nice page-changing effect in my project. Here is my script...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// Start-Up Page Load (Cover, ToC, etc.)
$('#content').load('pages/page1.htm');

// Navigating Pages
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {

    if ($(this).attr('target') == '_blank') {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    var ahref = $(this).attr('href');
    var $c = $('#content');
    var $cc = $('#content_container');

    $c.fadeTo('fast', 0.0, function() {
        $cc.animate({height: 'hide'}, 500);
        $c.load(ahref + '#content/', function(){
            $cc.animate({height: 'show'}, 500, function(){
                var x = $($c.children()[1]).children();
                var waittime = 0;
                for (item in x) {
                    item.delay(waittime).fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
                    waittime += 500;
                }
                // Failsafe that loads the entire page contents, in case the element-by-element animation does not work.
                // $c.fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
            });
        });
    });

    return false;

});

});
```

What I need to do is go through each and every specific tag in the remote content. I do this first by setting the `var waittime` to a number to help adjust the delay times because the elements tended to load at the same time in earlier tries, then (supposed to) loop through each HTML element and fade each one in, one at a time.

I have used the `.each()` and `.children()` methods and got bad results on page load. Through trial and error, I found that this line:

`$($c.children()[1]).children()`

Fetches each top-level HTML tag as an object. But when I tried running through that code using either `item` or `$(item)`, the console reads an error.

I don't think it gets text-nested elements like `<span>`. But if it did, doing so will interrupt the flow of the animation, so I don't know how jQuery can nitpick that out (though I noticed it doesn't, because it's reading the top-level). In other words, it should do the whole `<p>`, `<span>` inside it included, at the same time.

Taking the above into account, I noticed it did everything at the first level. It should be able to do whole elements nested inside whole elements individually, such as the `<dt>` and `<dd>`  inside a `<dl>`.

How do these HTML objects being fetched work? For some reason the console is telling me things like `.fadeTo()` is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

I used `setTimeout` with `each` to animate elements in sequence. my code is like below:

```
    var panels = $(".panel");
    panels.each(function(i) {
        var $panel = $(this);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $panel.css("display", "block")
                .addClass('fadeInDown animated')
                .one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function () {
                $panel.removeClass('fadeInDown animated');
            });
        }, i * 200);
    });
```

you can use CSS3 animations and add classes to elements.